# What are good alternatives to adobe software (InDesign, Photoshop and Illustrator)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, software-recommendation

Is there any professional software (for Mac) that I can use to replace some of the adobe software like InDesign, Photoshop and Illustrator?

I don’t mean one that replaces all, but the equivalent of each one.

Comment: Have you tried alternativeto.net? That's sometimes a good starting point. Have you tried google? You surely can't be the first person asking this question.

Answer (score 7):

Our tag wikis for [Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/adobe-illustrator/info), [Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/adobe-photoshop/info) and (now) [InDesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/adobe-indesign/info) have listings for alternative software that has been discussed on this site. It is not an exhaustive list of all programs out there, only ones that we have tags for:

#### Photoshop / Alternative Software: [adobe-photoshop-elements](/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop-elements) [gimp](/questions/tagged/gimp) [corel-paint-shop-pro](/questions/tagged/corel-paint-shop-pro) [paint.net](/questions/tagged/paint.net)

#### Illustrator / Alternative Software: [corel-draw](/questions/tagged/corel-draw) [inkscape](/questions/tagged/inkscape) [sketch](/questions/tagged/sketch)

#### InDesign / Alternative Software: [scribus](/questions/tagged/scribus) [quarkxpress](/questions/tagged/quarkxpress)

Answer (score 6):

I know others are recommending alternativeto which is where I started my search.  Having tried most of the top applications there, my recommendations would be as follows:

- Photoshop alternative: [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)
- Illustrator alternative: [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)
- InDesign alternative: [Lucidpress](http://www.lucidpress.com)

For the latter, I have tried Scribus. It was pretty difficult for me to pick up (frankly just like InDesign).  I recently switched to Lucidpress and have been impressed.

Comment: I use Scribus regularly. It's lacking some features that InDesign has, but it's a very good package. Verison 1.5 has made some big strides in closing that feature gap.

Answer (score 4):

as stated by KMSTR you should check out [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/) and it provides feedback on alternative applications and user comments.

- [Photoshop alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-photoshop/)
- [Illustrator alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-illustrator/)
- [InDesign alternative](http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-indesign/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Affinity Photo](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/beta-download/) beta (instead of Photoshop) for a while now and it's a great alternative! AP even uses most of the same keyboard shortcuts as PS, and the UI is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen others use Fire Alpaca, a software that mimics Photoshop in many ways. Its user friendly, and similar to Photoshop in tools and menus. A student of mine found it and used it for a graphic novel spread. It handles both high res pixel-based images and low-res output.

http://firealpaca.com/en